# Mock/unit test for this IRepositoryService method/class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq

I have the below code:

```
public interface IRepositoryService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This will add conditions like Published = true, Deleted = false and PublisehdDate smaller than NOW
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    IRavenQueryable<T> AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend<T>(IRavenQueryable<T> query) where T : BaseObject;


}

public class HomepageBannerRepository : BaseRepository<HomepageBanner>, IHomepageBannerRepository
{
    public HomepageBannerRepository(IRepositoryService repositoryService)
        : base(repositoryService)
    {

    }

    public List<HomepageBanner> GetHomepageBanners()
    {
        var q = CreateQuery(loadOnlyItemsAvailableToFrontend: true, autoSortByPriority: true);
        var list = q.ToList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

The method `IRepositoryService.AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend()` adds general conditions to any query like `Published=True` and `Deleted=False`, as all my objects inherit from `BaseObject` which contains fields like `Published`, `Deleted` etc.

This has been tested, and for the method `HomepageBannerRepository.GetHomepageBanners()`, I would only like to verify that it was called (using mocks), rather than having to check via unit-testing that only published items are returned.

The current unit test I created is as below (using the `SpecsFor` framework)

```
        [TestFixture]
        public class GetHomepageBannerSpecs
        {
            [TestFixture]
            public class when_method_is_called : SpecsForRepository<HomepageBannerRepository>
            {
                private HomepageBanner _bannerA;
                private HomepageBanner _bannerB;
                private HomepageBanner _bannerC;
                private List<HomepageBanner> _results;

                private HomepageBanner createHomepageBanner()
                {
                    HomepageBanner banner = new HomepageBanner();
                    banner.Store();

                    return banner;
                }

                protected override void Given()
                {
                    _bannerA = createHomepageBanner();
                    _bannerB = createHomepageBanner();
                    _bannerC = createHomepageBanner();

                    GetMockFor<IRepositoryService>();
                    base.Given();
                }

                protected override void When()
                {
                    _results = SUT.GetHomepageBanners();
                    base.When();
                }

                [Test]
                public void then_it_should_return_all_homepage_banners()
                {
                    GetMockFor<IRepositoryService>().Verify(x => x.AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend(It.IsAny<IRavenQueryable<HomepageBanner>>()), Times.Once());
                    GetMockFor<IRepositoryService>().Verify(x => x.AddSortByPriorityToQuery(It.IsAny<IRavenQueryable<HomepageBanner>>()), Times.Once());

                    _results.ShouldContain(_bannerA);
                    _results.ShouldContain(_bannerB);
                    _results.ShouldContain(_bannerC);

                }
            }
        }
```

The main problem stems from that the actual implementation of `HomepageBannerRepository.GetHomepageBanners()` requires that the implementation of the `IRepositoryService` returns a query, when `IRepositoryService.AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend` is called.  Since I am using a mock, this returns NULL, and then it throws an `ObjectNullReference` exception.

First of all, is it possible to setup the Mock to return the same parameter passed as input parameter? Something like:

```
GetMockFor(IRepositoryService).Setup(x=>x.AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend(query)).Returns(query);
```

I am using `Moq` as my mocking framework.

Also, I would like to receive any criticism regarding code, and where it could be structured better with regards to unit-testing / Test-Driven Development, dependency injection and any other comments are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Nice thing in participating/answering in forums like this is that you learn while you answer questions. I haven't heard about SpecsFor framework. Looks a bit tricky, but will definitely have a look later. Ok, back to your question :)

About your first question, setting up the mock - you can definitely do that, there are a number of overloaded `Returns` methods accepting delegate/lambda, depending on the number of parameters in the method being setup (here I setup the method to always return the same query regardless of the query passed:

```
GetMockFor(IRepositoryService)
    .Setup(x => x.AddConditionsToQueryToLoadOnlyAvailableForFrontend(It.IsAny<IRavenQueryable<HomepageBanner>>()))
    .Returns(q => q);
```

The code overally looks good except that Ayende suggests (and I completely agree with him) not to wrap RavenDB sessions into repositories. I would just create an extension method to add these filters to `IRavenQueryable<T> where T:BaseObject`